# How to convert a byte array into a .NET Object?

Tags: powershell-2.0

I am making a REST call from a PowerShell script called Insert and it is returning a byte Array. I would like to know how to convert this byte array in to an Object.

Comment: What kind of object? type `[object]` or `[object[]]` ?

Comment: my REST Insert method returns below data which I would like to convert it like .NET object so that I can use use other part of the script.[60,63,120,109,108,32,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,61,34,49,46,48,34,32,101,110,99,111,100,105,110,103,61,34,117,116,102,45,56,34,32,115,116,97,110,100,97,108,111,110,101,61,34,121,101,115,34,63
,62,13,10,60,101,110,116,114,121,32,120,109,108,58,98,97,115,101,61,34,104,116,116,112,58,47,47,108,111,99,97,108,104,111,115,116,47,82,101,112,111,115,105,116,111,114,121,47,100,97,116,97,47,7
0,108,101,120,105,98,108,101,67,111,109,112,117,116,105]

Comment: sorry it's [object[]] type

Comment: Um... How you want to use it? An array is simple to manage... Try explain what is your goal. Maybe an array can be enought...

Comment: I am inserting a database record using REST call(Insert)with Name and Status columns and then it return back as UniqueId,Name and Status as above byte array(I checked response in Fiddler and it coming back as expected). I want to convert above byte array to either Array or object. Couple of lines from my code...$workflowOperationData = Insert $metaDataUrl $jsonData 
 
   $workflowOperationArgumentsUrl = "/WorkflowOperations()?`$filter=WorkflowOperationId eq $workflowOperationData.WorkflowOperationId"

Comment: You can add your actual code clicking on edit to your question... comments aren't good for posting code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a starting point, converting to  string your byte array, but it seem to be incomplete:

```
$a = 60,63,120,109,108,32,118,101,114,115,105,111,110,61,34,49,46,48,34,32,101,110,99,111,100,105,110,103,61,34,117,11
6,102,45,56,34,32,115,116,97,110,100,97,108,111,110,101,61,34,121,101,115,34,63 ,62,13,10,60,101,110,116,114,121,32,120,
109,108,58,98,97,115,101,61,34,104,116,116,112,58,47,47,108,111,99,97,108,104,111,115,116,47,82,101,112,111,115,105,116,
111,114,121,47,100,97,116,97,47,70,108,101,120,105,98,108,101,67,111,109,112,117,116,105

( $a | % { -join [char]$_  }  ) -join ''

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry xml:base="http://localhost/Repository/data/FlexibleComputi
```

Comment: Perfect- I am able to see complete string using above line of code. Yes I have pasted cut short version of orginal Byte array.What should I do to access content properties of resultant string? <content type="application/xml">
    <m:properties>
      <d:WorkflowOperationId m:type="Edm.Int64">35</d:WorkflowOperationId>
      <d:Name>SystemProvisioned</d:Name>
      <d:Status>Initialize</d:Status>
    </m:properties>
  </content>

Comment: Cast to [xml] and then use select-xml cmdlet to query it.

Comment: Thanks C.B.You really saved lot of my time!